# What is the process for animating rigid bodies and then having them switch to dynamic?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

Good Afternoon,

I am attempting to learn the intricacies of Blender and I am stumped by the animation. I am trying to put my own spin on the typical wrecking ball into blocks, in that the ball swings into the blocks and breaks into pieces rather than the blocks falling over.

I have cell fractured the wrecking ball and I am trying to get all the pieces to move together via animation. Its a basic fracture, resulting in only 8 pieces. Here is my workflow:

-Cell fracture a UV sphere
-Make them active rigid bodies
-Attach to chain
-Keyframe the loc/rot, keyframe the animated property
-Advance the timeline, rotate ball into place and add loc/rot and animation keyframe

Its at this point I'm unsure of what to do next. Ideally, I'd like to have the ball swing down dynamically towards the wall and then right before contact is made (i have the blocks set to passive rigid bodies) have the ball just fall apart.

I've tried using 'Connect' under Rigid Bodies, however I'm not sure exactly how that constraint works and it seems to jitter around too much to be truly useful for this purpose.

To sum it up, I'd like to know how exactly to keyframe an object to be animated for half the frames and then dynamic for the other half.

Your help is greatly appreciated. I have been trying to figure this out for the past 5 days!

Comment: Keyframe "animated" on for the last frame that you want to retain control of the objects.  Advance one frame, turn off "animated", keyframe it.

Comment: Would I start the sim with all the objects keyframed "animated" on, or would the first instance of "animated" on be during the last frame you described?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have an initial keyframe set to animated.  It matters only that the final controlled frame is keyframed.

Answer (score 0):

I need some advice with this aswell. I can get my rigid bodies to get up to speed by animating them the first few frames. Turning on and keyframing dynamic works to start a physics animation.

When i try to switch it back to animated and keyframe it my body just goes back to the last position i animated it in before.

I can´t figure out how to take control of it again after the simulation in the same place as it sits.